# Order the following expressions by their size

Tags: combinatorics

> Order the following expressions by their size (suppose n is very large):
>
> $$\binom{2n}{n-1}, \binom{2n}{n},\binom{2n}{10}, n!, n^\sqrt{n},(\sqrt{n})^\sqrt{n}, n^{15}, n^{\log{n}}, (\log {n})^n, \log ({n}^n), 2^n  $$

I know that $\left(\begin{matrix} 2n \\ 10\end{matrix}\right) \le\left(\begin{matrix} 2n \\ n-1\end{matrix}\right) \le \left(\begin{matrix} 2n \\ n\end{matrix}\right)$ because the combination number $\left(\begin{matrix} n \\ k\end{matrix}\right)$ increases the closer it gets to $\left(\begin{matrix} n \\ \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} n \\ \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\end{matrix}\right)$ I also know that $ n^{15} \le n! \le n^n$

Comment: Relevant link for relating the binomial coefficients to the others: [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).

Comment: In General: Logs $\ll$ Polynomials $\ll$ exponentials $\ll$ factorials $\ll n^n$.  It will also help to remember that $x = e^{\ln x}$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: Use the Stirling formula to show that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is on the order of $\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n}}$.